# iPhone reuse sender after dismissed modal view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have 15 buttons on my app, which are displayed as an image. When I click on an image the getEventContact function is called which brings up a modal view controller. In this next view a contact is selected - the modal view is dismissed and the setEventContact function is run (to return the selected contact (which is its own class)).

Is there a way to determine the previous sender which triggered the getEventContact function as it could be one of 15 buttons.

```
-(IBAction)getEventContact:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"selectContact" sender:self];
}

-(void)setEventContact:(Contact *)selectedContact
{
    //do something
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: If you're presenting/dismissing a modal view controller your data will stick around. Just write the sender to a variable and then look at it in your `setEventContact` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SomeType *someVariable;

-(IBAction)getEventContact:(id)sender 
{
    someVariable = sender;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"selectContact" sender:self];
}

-(void)setEventContact:(Contact *)selectedContact
{
    //not a real method
    [someVariable someMethod];
}
```